# RDKit image MolToImage scales Bond widths and Element Labels inconsistently for different image sizes?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rdkit

I've noticed that when I create an image from a molecule in RDKit, the `size` argument leads to inconsistent scaling of the bond width and element labels. The bigger the size, the thinner the lines and the smaller the element labels.

I've run a test by generating an image for the same molecule using `MolToImage` at progressively bigger sizes. I rescaled those images to `size=(600,600)` and then concatenated them into a GIF. This is the result.

[image: Resulting GIF]

Here's my code

```py
from glob import glob
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageFont


def make_frames_from_smi(smi):

    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi)

    for i in range(10):
        s = (i+3)*100
        mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi)
        img = Draw.MolToImage(mol,size=(s,s))
        img = img.resize((600,600))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

        text = '%d: Initial Size: (%d,%d)'%(i+1,s,s)

        font_size = 40
        font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", font_size)  # Use your desired font


        # Calculate text position
        image_width, image_height = img.size
        text_x = (image_width - (bbox[2] - bbox[0])) // 2
        text_y = 20  # Adjust the vertical position as needed

        draw.text((text_x, text_y), text, font=font, fill='black')
        img.save('%03dtest.png'%i)


def make_gif_from_frames(paths):

    frames_paths = glob(paths)
    frames = [Image.open(imgp) for imgp in frames_paths]

    frames[0].save("mols.gif", format="GIF", append_images=frames, save_all=True, duration=500, loop=False)



# make RDKit mol obj.
smi = 'CN(C)CC1CCCCC1(C2=CC(=CC=C2)OC)O'
make_frames_from_smi(smi)
make_gif_from_frames('*.png')
```

Is this expected behaviour? Is the bond width held constant for a certain absolute value of pixels? How can I generate these images with consistent proportions regardless of width/height of pixels?